# Render delimited list in XAML?

Tags: wpf, silverlight, list, xaml, styles

Is there a general-purpose XAML styling or templating technique to render a databound list of items as a delimited list on screen?

Imagine outputing something like a function call declaration in XAML:  `foo(a,b,c)` where "a", "b", and "c" come from a databound list.  ("foo" is databound, too, but not to the parameter list)

The "a", "b", and "c" elements need to remain XAML UI elements so they can be UI interactive and stylable in XAML.  (So I think this disqualifies simple string concatenation as a solution)

The critical point is to **not** have a spurious trailing comma at the end of the list.

This is somewhat related to the question of **how to style the first and/or last elements in a list differently from the middle elements**.  I've seen suggestions here on stackoverflow to use an `ItemsTemplateSelector` in an `ItemsControl` to test whether an item is the first or last in the list and return the appropriate template, but the problem with that is the `DataTemplateSelector.SelectTemplate` has no access to the list that the item came from.  You can hack carnal knowledge of a particular list as a one-off kludge, but how do you do this in a general purpose, reusable way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In WPF, you can use a binding with relative source PreviousData. If previous data is null, you know it's the first item in the list, so no need to prepend a separator.

Alas, Silverlight doesn't support this and I was unable to find a nice workaround when I had the exact same requirement. I ended up just setting a margin such that the trailing comma would never be visible.

Comment: BTW: The PreviousData binding does not update when using ObservableCollection<T>.Move(int,int) to reorder items.